# disable "sharewith" from the Ribbon and share option in sharepoint 2019

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I need to disable `Shared With` option from the ribbon and the sharing of an item for all users:

[image]

[image]

I used these two PowerShell commands but that doesn't work:

```
Disable-SPFeature -Identity "FollowingContent" -URL $web
```

and

```
$web.RequestAccessEmail = ""
```

I checked the `$web.RequestAccessEnabled = false`

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disabling `Access Request Settings` would help you to

- Disallow members to share and invite others to this site,
- Disallow access requests to unauthorized members.
- Limit some SharePoint sharing functionality for specific members.

**But**, it's not considered a solution to hide or disable the “Shared With” or the “Share” Menu Item for `all users`. **Instead**, you should use CSS!

[image]

> - For the **list**, Please check [How to Disable the `"Shared With"` and `"Share"` button in SharePoint?](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/disable-shared-with-in-sharepoint-online/)
> - For the **Document Library**, Please check [How to disable Share in SharePoint Document Library?](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/disable-share-in-sharepoint-document-library/)

Comment: Thanks Mohamed, it works !

Answer (score 0):

Try to use css to prohibit these two buttons from being clickable：

```
<style>
#Ribbon.Library.Settings.LibraryPermissions-Large,#ID_Share{
pointer-events: none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: well it doesnot work for me!

Comment: This css code just makes the two share buttons unclickable, and it still looks normal. If it does not work, you need to replace it with the corresponding id selector in your environment.